# Is there a deep reason why math books use the phrase "is called" in definitions?

Tags: terminology

I am trying to struggle through some basic math textbooks and I noticed that in definitions they usually use the following phrasing: "A function $f:X \to Y$ is called *one-to-one* if..." I was wondering if there was a deep reason why they don't say "A function $f:X \to Y$ is *one-to-one* if..." or if it could be said either way.

Comment: No; we simply "name" it; we "baptize" that specified kind of function with the name *one-to-one*.

Comment: Without the "is called" and without further context your phrasing could be stating a theorem about one-to-one functions rather than a definition. I agree that Inside a formal definition you could safely omit "is called", but it's better to be safe than rely on context.

Comment: In my experience I have found most textbooks *do* so "is" rather than "is called".  But shouldn't it be obvious that if we are *defining* an expression for the first time that the phrase will have no meaning until it is defined.  To say A function is one-to-one when one-to-one is meaningless is meaningless.  And if one-to-one is meaningful then to say a function "is" one-to-one when it fulfills the meaning is redundant.  A definition is neither of those cases.  A definition is a declaration that "this is what a phrase *means*".  Sure the deep difference of that is obvious.

Comment: If the statement is floating amid the general text of an article, "is called *one-to-one*" can help highlight that you're making a definition. You can achieve the same end with a structure like "Definition. A function [...] is *one-to-one* if ..". Generally, you can do what you want, so long as your intention is clear to the reader. After all, you might also want to use *emphasis* for descriptive phrases that aren't definitional: "a function that does this-or-that is *weird* ..."

Comment: It signals that the statement is a definition, rather than a theorem.

Comment: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~chechik/courses/csc324/white.html

Comment: @LeeMosher He who got Carroll's message got it all ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's to distinguish the act of *introducing a name* from *stating a claim*.

If I write

> A *foo* is *blah* iff it *gleens*,

it's unclear whether I'm defining the notion of a "*blah foo*" or if I'm claiming that I can prove that the *blah foos* are exactly the ones which *gleen*. By contrast, if I write

> A *foo* is called *blah* iff it *gleens*,

it's clear that what I mean is that I'm *introducing* the term "*blah*" here. Basically, this is letting the reader know that they haven't missed the definition of "$blah$" earlier in the text, and that I'm not tacitly assuming that they already know what "*blah*" means. Note that in mathematical writing, we often do state "immediate" observations without proof (e.g. "A function is injective iff it has a left inverse"), so confusion is definitely possible here.

(Unfortunately this isn't universally used.)

Answer (score 1):

"is called" is a statement about phrases and meaning.  "is" is a statement about actual existence.

To state: "A function, $f:X\to Y$ is one-to-one if for any $x\in X; y\in Y$ so that $f(x)=y$ then there is no other $z \in X; z \ne x$ so that $f(z) = f(x)$" when "one-to-one" has not been defined is meaningless because "one-to-one" is meaningless (at this time).

To state: "A function, $f:X\to Y$ is one-to-one if for any $x\in X; y\in Y$ so that $f(x)=y$ then there is no other $z \in X; z \ne x$ so that $f(z) = f(x)$" when "one-to-one" has  been defined is redundant because that is what one-to-one *means* so this statement is pointless and repetitive.

To *define* what "one-to-one" means the first time we must make a statement that says:  "We will use a phrase $X$ to mean this particular condition $C$". But this is a statement about the phrase "one-to-one" and declaring its meaning.  It isn't actually declaring anything about the universe that isn't already known (merely that will will be referring to a concept by a specific term.)